# How do you get the return key to execute code in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8

In xcode, using Swift, I need to be able to execute a line of code using the return key on the software keyboard.

How do I specify this?

I know how to resignFirstResponder for the software keyboard but that is all at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### for a UITextField:

a `UITextFieldDelegate` has the method `textFieldShouldReturn:` that is called . Do your stuff and return NO to prevent a newline / yes for multiline

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)field {
   //DO your stuff
   return NO; // yes to allow enter 
}
```

### for a UITextView:

the delegate has `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text`

check if text is return and do the above.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ( [text isEqualToString:@"\n"] ) {
        //Do whatever you want
    }
    return YES;
}
```